# How to change a @State variable from a different struct

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am new to swift UI and swift in general, and I was wondering how to change a variable from a different struct. In this case, I need to change the logged in boolean in a content view from this section in a different view. Basic explanations would be appreciated. Thanks!

```swift
Button(action: {

    if (checkKey(testKey: self.key)) {

        //HERE

    }

}) {
    Text("Submit")
    .padding()
.background(Color.init(.sRGB, red: 0.01, green: 0.01, blue: 0.01, opacity: 0.05))
            .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

And this is the Content View. I need to change the @State bool

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State public var loggedin: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            if (loggedin) {

                MainView()

            } else {
                // Not Logged In
                LoginScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't change the state bool of another view like that. You should create an observable object for your data model and then share an instance between the two views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is a full code you can pass your `@State public var loggedin: Bool` variable to another struct using `@Binding var loggedin: Bool` and chnage value

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State public var loggedin: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if (loggedin) {
            MainView(loggedin: $loggedin)
        } else {
            // Not Logged In
            LoginScreen(loggedin: $loggedin)
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
struct MainView: View {
@Binding var loggedin: Bool
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("")
        Button(action: {
            self.loggedin = false
        }, label: {
            Text("Chnage loggedin value")
        })
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This should work, but I get an error with this code. I don't know exactly what the code does, but what should I put in the argument for the preview provider. It requires an argument when calling LoginScreen() "LoginScreen(loggedin:  Binding<Bool> )"

Comment: you can pass like this  LoginScreen(loggedin: .constant(false))

Answer (score 2):

```
@Binding var loggedin: Bool
```

in your login screen view. If you only use the login here its fine like this, if you are using it across the app you might want to look into @EnvironmentObject.